# Stucked: Can't finde a Zoho Deluge code to integrate Zoho Form on a new Record in Zoho CRM

Tags: json, forms, crm, zoho, zoho-deluge

Good morning/afternoon/evening, community. I'm encountering an issue while using Zoho Flow to create a record upon the submission of a Zoho Form (I'm not using the native integration because this form is intended for clients). The problem is that I have fields that are checkboxes, and every output from the form is input as a string when creating a new record in Zoho CRM. As a result, I never get a boolean value for the checkboxes in Zoho CRM.

This is my actual function:

```
bool marketing_checkbox_boolean(list marketing_requires_list)
{
marketing_fullList = {"Create newsletters (Mkt - admin)","Create social media calendar","Post on Social Medias (LinkedIn/Facebook/Instagram/Twitter)","Send Newsletters","Monitor online traffic and report results.","Assist with the web design and development.","Create simple graphics on Canva","Create videos","Create posts about success stories.","Reply messages on social media","Delete/Report negative comments on social media (LinkedIn/Facebook/Instagram/Twitter)","Website Audit for outdated information.","Help to create sales materials (i.e./Presentations/Banners/Mailings/Brochures/Decks)"};
verification = marketing_fullList.contains(marketing_requires_list);
return verification;
}
```

I was told about a function called map() that might help me, but I can't find it on the Zoho Deluge page. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Regards!
[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLbHd.png)
[Entire flow screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBpul.png)

Comment: Hey there! To get an anwser, make sure to have your question in one line after explaining your problem, it helps people understand your problem easier, and also make sure to always provide an exemple of what you're doing, sometime it's hard to extract and post on stack overflow, but always remember that stack overflow is community ran and isn't a support line. With that being said, I think you'd get better help with your question if you re-structured it 

1 - What's the problem
2 - What have you tried
3 - Desirable outcome
4 - One line resuming your question
5 - Code sample

This way you ensur

Answer (score 0):

`Map()` is not a function, but a data type. You can use it to pass values between Zoho applications and modules.

```
responseReturn = Map();
responseReturn.put("key","value");
```

You can transpose this to either a string (`toString()`), or a JSON payload (`toJSONList()`) or to a list (`toList()`).